# dependency service does not work when using certain interface

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am using dependency service in my application. I have declared interface, registered the service in MainActivity and AppDelegate and still the value of my bool is false. However if I used different interface that is already used in the native project then it works correctly. There is no difference in implementation at all. Please note that when I switch between services I comment out the other interface.

```
MainActivity/AppDelegate

  DependencyService.Register<ICustomSettings, ExtractionService>();

Class in Native project

[assembly: Dependency(typeof(ExtractionService))]
public class ExtractionService : IExtractService, ICustomSettings
    {
       
        private bool isMultipage = false;

 public bool IsMultiPage(bool isSetMultipage)
        {
            isMultipage = isSetMultipage;
            return isMultipage;
        }
}

ViewModel
{
    private readonly IExtractService _extractService = DependencyService.Get<IExtractService>();
    private readonly ICustomSettings _customService= DependencyService.Get<ICustomSettings>();
}

  public bool IsMultiPage
        {
            get => SettingsService.MultipageProcessing;
            set
            {
                SettingsService.MultipageProcessing = value;
                _customService.IsMultiPage(IsMultiPage);
                NotifyPropertyChanged("IsMultiPage");
            }
        }

 private void ExecuteMultiPageCommand(bool value)
        {
            _customService.IsMultiPage(value);
            SettingsService.MultipageProcessing = value;
        }

Interface

 public interface ICustomSettings
    {
        bool IsMultiPage(bool isMultipage);

    }

 public interface IExtractService
    {
        bool IsMultiPage(bool isMultipage);
   
    }
```

Any Suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Due to i do not have the `SettingsService.MultipageProcessing`, i make a simple example for your reference.

**ViewModel.cs:** The original value of the `IsMultiPage` is false. Because we set it to false in  `ExtractionService`.

```
 public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ViewModel()
    {
        this.IsMultiPage = true;
    }
     
    private readonly IExtractService _extractService = DependencyService.Get<IExtractService>();
    private readonly ICustomSettings _customService = DependencyService.Get<ICustomSettings>();

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public bool _isMultiPage;

    public bool IsMultiPage
    {
        get { return this._isMultiPage; }
        //get => SettingsService.MultipageProcessing;
        set
        {
            this._isMultiPage= value ;
            //SettingsService.MultipageProcessing = value;
            _customService.IsMultiPage(_isMultiPage);
            NotifyPropertyChanged("IsMultiPage");
        }
    }

    private void ExecuteMultiPageCommand(bool value)
    {
        _customService.IsMultiPage(value);
        //SettingsService.MultipageProcessing = value;
    }
}
```

**ExtractionService.cs:**

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(ExtractionService))]
namespace Test.Droid
{
public class ExtractionService: IExtractService, ICustomSettings
{
  
    private bool isMultipage = false;
    public bool IsMultiPage(bool isSetMultipage)
    {
        isMultipage = isSetMultipage;
        return isMultipage;
    }
}
}
```

**BindingContent:**

```
 this.BindingContext = new ViewModel();
```

When i set the `IsMultiPage` with true in ViewModel, it would return true. If i misunderstand what you want, please feel free to let me know.